# orthogonalize matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy, orthogonal

I tried to orthogonalize a `2d-numpy array` and failed. I used [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Nearest_orthogonal_matrix) approach and translated it to this code:

```
def sym(w):
    return w.dot((w.T.dot(w))**(-.5))
```

but

```
In [1]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  1.1]])
In [3]: a = sym(a)

In [4]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1.20909392,  2.43574363],
       [ 2.43574363,  1.20909392]])

In [6]: a.dot(a.T)
Out[7]: 
array([[ 7.39475513,  5.89008563],
       [ 5.89008563,  7.39475513]])
```

`a.dot(a.T)` should output the identity.

Comment: The `sym` function doesn't have any connection to the line `a.dot(a.T)`- should it?

Comment: you are right, I am going to edit the example!

Comment: I find the behavior of `**.5` quite strange in general, as let `a` be some square matrix : `b=a**.5` then `a != b.dot(b.T)`. Which is not, what I expected...

Comment: I believe you want [scipy.linalg.sqrtm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.sqrtm.html) for the matrix square root

Comment: thats correct, now, `a == b.dot(b.T)` outputs True, when `b = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(a)` ! Thanks a lot, but still, @DavidRobinson, do you have an answer, why my orthogonalization doesn't work, even when I change the square root function?

Comment: It seems to be to the power of -.5 instead of to the power of .5. Do you know if this means that it is the inverse of the matrix square root? (Also, can you update your question to show the new code?)

Comment: correct answer. after using the inverse, it worked. should I paste the correct code as answer or as edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The working definition of `sym` is:

```
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm, inv

def sym(w):
    return w.dot(inv(sqrtm(w.T.dot(w))))
```

This is because raising a numpy matrix to the power of -.5 is not equivalent to taking the [matrix square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) and then inverting it, which is what the formula requires.